# Creating popup bubble on Google Maps API

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to create popup bubbles on Google Maps API. Here is what I wanted to do. Let say I am driving from Point A to Point B and I would like popup bubble to show popular places when I am nearby that particular area while I am on the way from point A to point B. And is there any special term for that function? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There currently isn't a function or a view for that, but you could easily create your own custom one. For example, you could make a `TextView` that has a custom background, and just put that on top of your Google Maps fragment.

To put a view on top of a fragment, you would have to put the fragment into a layout, such as a `RelativeLayout`, like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.akashbhave.locomoto.MapsDemo">

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.akashbhave.locomoto.MapsDemo" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/infoView"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:background="@drawable/infoViewLayout"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="7dp"
    android:paddingLeft="7dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You could then create an XML file that has a shape, and set that as your background, like I did above. 
Whenever the user came by a popular place (you could check for that in your Java code), just set the `infoView` to visible, or invisible if the user left. An example would be:

```
// Check distance to locations here (possible through loc1.distanceTo(loc2))
if(distance < targetDistance) {
    infoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
else {
    infoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

If you just wanted to show a quick popup, you could use a `Toast`, like so:

```
Toast.makeText(MapsDemo.this, "You are near" + locationName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

That's about it! Hope it helps!